# Run my own application on hadoop without coding mapreduce?

Tags: c#, .net, hadoop, mapreduce

Maybe I did not fully understand how complex hadoop really is, if there is something incorrect please help me out. So what I got is this:

Hadoop is a great thing to handle a big amount of data. Mostly for data analysis and mining. I can write my own mapreduce functions or using pig or hive. I can even use existing functions, `wordcount` and stuff like that - I dont even have to write code.

Ok, but what if I would like to use the great power of hadoop for non-analysis/mining things? As example I have a .NET application written in C# that is able to read files and generating pdfs with some barcodes. This application is running on one server, but because the one server cannot handle the big amount of files I need more power. Why not adding some hadoop nodes/clusters to handle this job?

Question: can I take my .NET application and tell hadoop "do this, on every on your nodes/cluster"? -> Running these jobs without coding, is it possible?

If not, do I have to throw away the .NET application and rewrite everything in pig/hive/java-mapreduce? Or how do people solve these issues in my situation?

PS: The important thing here is not the pdf generator and maybe also not .NET/C# - the question is: there is an application in language `whatever` - can I give it to hadoop just like that? Or do we have to rewrite everything in mapreduce functions?

Answer (score 0):

@Mongo : I'm not sure if I understood correct but I'd try sharing what I know. First of all hadoop is a framework - not an extension or a plugin.

If you want to process the files or perform a task in hadoop, you need to make sure that your requirements are properly put forward so that hadoop understand what to do with your data. To put it simple, let us consider the same word count example. If you want to perform the word count on a file, you can do it using any language. Lets say we have done it in Java, and we want to scale it to larger files- dumping the same code in to a hadoop cluster would not be helpful. Though the java logic remains the same, you will have to write a Map reduce code in java which would be understood by the hadoop framework.

Here's an example of a [C# map reduce program](http://www.codeguru.com/columns/experts/how-to-create-mapreduce-jobs-for-hadoop-using-c.htm) for Hadoop processing
Here's another example of [MapReduce Without Hadoop Using the ASP.NET Pipeline](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt147240.aspx)

Hope this is helpful. I'm assuming that my post adds some value to your question. I'm sure you would be getting better thoughts/suggestions/answers from the wonderful people here...

P.S: You could mostly do anything and everything thats related to file processing/ data analysis in Hadoop. It all depends up on how you do it :)

Cheers !

Answer (score 0):

Any application that can run in Linux can be done in Hadoop, using [Hadoop-streaming](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/streaming.html). And a C# application can run in Linux using [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/).

So you can run your C# application using both Hadoop-streaming and Mono. But still, you need to adapt your logic to the map-reduce paradigm.

However, it should not be a big deal in your case. For instance, you could:

- create a Hadoop-streaming job with mappers only (no reducers)
- process exactly 1 file per mapper
- each mapper would run "mono yourApp.exe", reading the input file in stdin, and writing the output in stdout

Also, Mono must be available on the Hadoop cluster. If not, some admin privileges will be required to install and deploy Mono yourself.